# SQL query to find MAx row in subquery

Tags: sql, max, row, sql-server-2000

These are my tables:

```
User, Product, DiscountGroup, DiscountUser, DiscountProduct.
```

DiscountProduct:

```
id    discountGroupId    productId     discount
---   --------------     ---------     -------
1        2                8             2000
2        3                8             1000
3        2                4              4500
```

DiscountUser:

```
id    discountGroupId    userId   
---   --------------     --------- 
1        2                2        
2        3                3        
3        2                2
```

DiscountGroup:

```
id    title   active
---   ------ --------     
1       A      1         
2       B      0       
3       C       1
```

I use SQL Server 2000.

What I want :

first: for each productid and member find discountGroup that both of Them belong to it.

I write my query:

```
select * 
from discountGroup 
where id in (select discountgroupId 
             from discountproduct 
             where productid = 11)
  and id in (select discountgroupId 
             from discountuser 
             where userid = 2)
  and active = 1
```

Second: I want to find maximum discount for special product and member.

How can I do it?

Third: for special user and  all product I want to find the best discount and discountGroup Title:

Same this:

```
user  produc    discount   discountGroup
---   -----     -------    ------------
ali   phone     400            A
reeza mobile     200           B
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subqueries, use joins:

```
select g.id, p.discount
from DiscountGroup g
inner join DiscountProduct p on p.discountGroupId = g.id
inner join DiscountUser u on u.discountGroupId = g.id
where p.productid = 11 and u.userid = 2
```

To get the maximum discount, use the max aggregate:

```
select max(p.discount)
from DiscountGroup g
inner join DiscountProduct p on p.discountGroupId = g.id
inner join DiscountUser u on u.discountGroupId = g.id
where p.productid = 11 and u.userid = 2
```